# 2 bibliography with 2 bib files

Tags: bibliographies

I'd like to have

I've try this but it doesn't work. I've got a blank document.

Could you help me ? Thanks a lot

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multibbl}

\newbibliography{biblio1}
\newbibliography{biblio2}

\begin{document}



\nocite{biblio1}{*}

\bibliographystyle{bibli1}{plain}

\bibliography{biblio1}{bib1}{My bibliography 1}

\nocite{biblio2}{*}

\bibliographystyle{biblio2}{plain}

\bibliography{biblio2}{bib2}{My bibliography 2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo on the line `\bibliographystyle{bibli1}{plain}`, which should read `\bibliographystyle{biblio1}{plain}`.

However, probably your main problem has to do with the commands you are running to compile and generate the PDF file. To correctly produce this bibliography, you have to run the following commands in order (assuming that your source file is called `bibltest.tex`):

```
latex bibltest.tex
bibtex biblio1
bibtex biblio2
pdflatex bibltest.tex
```

The problem with the `multibbl` package is that editors do not automate this generation process by default.

[image: bibltest]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multibbl}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{bib1.bib}
    @book{aa,
        author = {aa},
        title = {{aa}},
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{bib2.bib} 
    @book{bb,
        author = {bb},
        title = {{bb}},
        }
\end{filecontents*}

\newbibliography{biblio1}
\newbibliography{biblio2}

\begin{document}



    \nocite{biblio1}{*}

    \bibliographystyle{biblio1}{plain}

    \bibliography{biblio1}{bib1}{My bibliography 1}

    \nocite{biblio2}{*}

    \bibliographystyle{biblio2}{plain}

    \bibliography{biblio2}{bib2}{My bibliography 2}

\end{document}
```